# pattern extraction from ls -l command's output

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract information from `ls -1hl` command.

I have to run this command on different remote servers and from each of them i get different kind of outputs as some of them are solaris and some of them are GNU linux

here is the snippet of `ls -1hl` command which i want to format:-

`ssh user@server 'ls -1hl /path/to/directory'`

ls_command:-

```
-rw-r-----   1 root groupA     0 2014-08-04 10:42 a.log
-rw-------   1 root  groupA  48132720 Aug  1 23:45 core
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  groupA      208 Mar 13 17:18 restart.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root groupA   49 2014-06-06 09:32 MerSem -> ../combined_ABC/scripts
drwxrwxrwx   3 root groupA     1.0K Apr 22 16:12 logs
```

i want to extract following information from the above snippet:-

For first line

```
permission = -rw-r-----  
links = 1
owner = rooot
group = groupA
size = 0
date = 2014-08-04 10:42
File/Directory Name = a.log
```

My code:-

```
Final_list = []
result = ls_command.split('\n')
for line in result:
   coldata = []
   a = re.search(r"^(.+?)\s{1,3}.*$",line)
   b = re.search(r"^.+?\s{1,3}(\d{1,5}).*$",line)
   c = re.search(r"^.+?\s{1,3}\d{1,5}(.+?)\s{1,3}.*$",line)
   d = re.search(r"^.+?\s{1,3}\d{1,5}.+?\s(.+?)\s{1,3}.*$",line)
   e = re.search(r"^.+?\s{1,3}\d{1,5}.+?\s.+?\s{1,3}([0-9.A-Za-z]+?)\s{1,3}.*$",line)
   f = re.search(r"^.+?\s{1,3}\d{1,5}.+?\s.+?\s{1,3}[0-9.A-Za-z]+?\s{1,3}(.+?)\s{1,3}.*$",line)
   g = re.search(r"^.*\s{1,3}(.+)$",line)
   if a:
           permissions = a.group(1)
   if b:
           links = b.group(1)
   if c:
           owner = c.group(1)
   if d:
           group = d.group(1)
   if e:
           size = e.group(1)
   if f:
           date = f.group(1)
   if g:
           filename = g.group(1)
   if a and b and c and d and e and f and g:
           coldata.append(permissions)
           coldata.append(links)
           coldata.append(owner)
           coldata.append(group)
           coldata.append(size)
           coldata.append(date)
           coldata.append(filename)
           Final_list.append(coldata)
```

But this code doesn't work with the kind of dates which i'm getting.

```
Print Final_list

 [['-rw-r-----','1','root','groupA','0','2014-08-04','a.log'],['-rw-------','1','root','groupA','48132720','Aug','core'],['-rwxr-xr-x','1','root','groupA','208','Mar','restart.sh'],['lrwxrwxrwx','1','root','groupA','49','2014-06-06','../combined_ABC/scripts'],['drwxrwxrwx','3','root','groupA','1.0K','Apr','logs']]
```

Expected output:-

```
[['-rw-r-----','1','root','groupA','0','2014-08-04 10:42 ','a.log'],['-rw-------','1','root','groupA','48132720','Aug  1 23:45','core'],['-rwxr-xr-x','1','root','groupA','208','Mar 13 17:18','restart.sh'],['lrwxrwxrwx','1','root','groupA','49','2014-06-06 09:32','MerSem -> ../combined_ABC/scripts'],['drwxrwxrwx','3','root','groupA','1.0K','Apr 22 16:12','logs']]
```

Comment: Wouldn't `os.stat` give you this information?

Comment: I would try using `split()` to split on the spaces and then you should have all the fields separated nicely

Comment: Better use `stat` instead.

Comment: `ls` is just a report generator around the `stat` system call, and is intended for human consumption. Use `stat` to retrieve the desired information about each file rather than trying to parse the output of `ls` (which in the most general case is [nearly impossible](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)).

Answer (score -1):

```
s="""
-rw-r-----   1 root groupA     0 2014-08-04 10:42 a.log
-rw-------   1 root  groupA  48132720 Aug  1 23:45 core
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  groupA      208 Mar 13 17:18 restart.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root groupA   49 2014-06-06 09:32 MerSem -> ../combined_ABC/scripts
drwxrwxrwx   3 root groupA     1.0K Apr 22 16:12 logs
"""

line = s.lstrip().split("\n")[0].split() # split on newline and split the first line 

permission = line[0]
links = line[1]
owner = line[2]
group = line[3]
size = line[4]
date = line[5]
Name = line[-1]

print permission,links,owner,group,size,date,Name
-rw-r----- 1 root groupA 0 2014-08-04 a.log
```

Comment: Your solution is very broken.  File names with spaces will break this, symlinks will break this. various date formats will break this, device files will break this.